# How to implement SSO using SAML in the existing ASP.net application

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml, azure-active-directory, ws-federation

I need to implement Single SignOn (SSO) in one of our ASP.net web applications for a client. I need to use one of the following protocols for this purpose.

1. WS-Fed
2. SAML

The identity provider(client's Domain) is Microsoft Azure Active Directory.

I have searched the internet but could not find any usefull implementation.

Could you please share with me your findings if you have gone through this experience.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the Katana middleware. Add an OWIN `Startup` class to your project and add this to the `Configuration` method:

```
var tenant = "yourdirectory.onmicrosoft.com";
var directory = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
var metadataAddress = string.Format(
    "{0}/{1}/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml",
        directory, tenant);

app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
    new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Wtrealm = realm,
        MetadataAddress = metadataAddress
    });
```

You can find a complete working example [on Github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation).

Answer (score 0):

If you're after a commercial product, our ComponentSpace SAML v2.0 library enables your ASP.NET application to act as either the identity provider or service provider in SAML SSO. Simply reference our DLL and call our API to enable SAML SSO. More information including a free evaluation download may be found http://www.componentspace.com.

Answer (score 0):

If your ASP.NET application is the service provider (SP).  Then an option would be to leverage Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) libraries.  Depending on the version of .NET your ASP.NET web application is using there are some slight differences in how the tags are added to the `web.config`.  For .NET 4.5, you will bring in the `system.identity.model` and then configure WS-Federation via the `<system.identityModel>` configuration, as well as you will need to setup the `<system.identityModel.services>` configuration with the `<wsfederation>` passive redirect.  The configuration requires you to setup the issuer as Microsoft Azure IdP.  The WIF libraries handle all the communication and protocol with the IdP, such that the attributes of the embedded SAML v1.1 token as returned via WS-Federation are available to your application via the `ClaimsIdentity` object.